# Error while converting Json to an array and iterating in html using for loop in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ngfor

I'm working with angular, I'm getting data from api get call for one of the column as below.
I converted this json to an array as mentioned. And when i iterate this over html, i'm getting error.
My goal is to iterate the below column data in html using ngfor.
Please help me achieve the functionality.

```
[{"Parent": null, "GradeCode": null, "BrandName": "CORONA", "Manufacturer": null, "Description": null, "BrandStatus": 1, "ManufacturerName": "", "ParentBrandName": "CORONA", "id": 7101}, 
{"Parent": "hhh", "GradeCode": null, "BrandName": "TSINGTAO", "Manufacturer": null, "Description": null, "BrandStatus": 1, "ManufacturerName": "", "ParentBrandName": "TSINGTAO", "id": 7100}]
```

I pushed this data to an array

```
data: any = [];
```

I converted the above i.e. "data" from json to array as below.
But, i'm getting the error as :

" ERROR TypeError: this.data.forEach is not a function.

```
data1=[];
  ngOnInit()
  {
    var StringifyData=JSON.stringify(this.data)
    console.log(this.data)
    this.data.forEach((item,index)=>{
        var obj;
        obj={
          Parent:item.Parent,
          text:item.BrandName,
        }
       this.data1.push(obj)
    });
     console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data1))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.data, item => {
//logic goes here... 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to push the array to the `data` object.

You can either assign or push the elements from the array to the `data` object.

So, you can either do this:

```
this.data = [
      {
        Parent: null,
        GradeCode: null,
        BrandName: "CORONA",
        Manufacturer: null,
        Description: null,
        BrandStatus: 1,
        ManufacturerName: "",
        ParentBrandName: "CORONA",
        id: 7101
      },
      {
        Parent: "hhh",
        GradeCode: null,
        BrandName: "TSINGTAO",
        Manufacturer: null,
        Description: null,
        BrandStatus: 1,
        ManufacturerName: "",
        ParentBrandName: "TSINGTAO",
        id: 7100
      }
    ];
```

Or this:

```
[
      {
        Parent: null,
        GradeCode: null,
        BrandName: "CORONA",
        Manufacturer: null,
        Description: null,
        BrandStatus: 1,
        ManufacturerName: "",
        ParentBrandName: "CORONA",
        id: 7101
      },
      {
        Parent: "hhh",
        GradeCode: null,
        BrandName: "TSINGTAO",
        Manufacturer: null,
        Description: null,
        BrandStatus: 1,
        ManufacturerName: "",
        ParentBrandName: "TSINGTAO",
        id: 7100
      }
    ];

    [
      {
        Parent: null,
        GradeCode: null,
        BrandName: "CORONA",
        Manufacturer: null,
        Description: null,
        BrandStatus: 1,
        ManufacturerName: "",
        ParentBrandName: "CORONA",
        id: 7101
      },
      {
        Parent: "hhh",
        GradeCode: null,
        BrandName: "TSINGTAO",
        Manufacturer: null,
        Description: null,
        BrandStatus: 1,
        ManufacturerName: "",
        ParentBrandName: "TSINGTAO",
        id: 7100
      }
    ].forEach(f => this.data.push(f));
```

**Note:** The first one is a better to attempt here.

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-au6upm?file=src/app/app.component.ts).